# how to get all the numbers greater than x with positions?

Tags: r

```
V <- c(1,3,2,4,2,3,1);

X <- 3;
pos <-V[V == X];
```

`pos` is `3 3`.
what I need is the positions of all 3;

I need `2` and `6`; which are the positions of `3` in `V`.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Use `which`

```
pos <- which(V == 3)
```

---

Not what you're asking for, but useful anyway: you can also use `which.min` and `which.max` to find the position of the minimum and maximum value of the array.

Comment: Didn't know about `which.max`. As luck would have it, I just needed it in my program. :)

Comment: Look out with `which.min` and `which,max` tho that they only return the first minimum or maximum element.

Comment: @Sacha Epskamp: good point. If you want ALL the minima (maxima) then use `which(V == max(V))`